# Dynamic - Automated multiplication - Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

after spending quite a while search and reading on Stackoverflow and around the web, I am desperate...

I have a Pandas DataFrame with some imported data (spectra). The first column is the wavelength while the others are the various spectra (the data). The names of the columns are imported from a list that reads the filenames from a path and keeps just the names.

What I would like to achieve and I can't quite seem to get how is to multiply each of the columns with the wavelength column and either overwrite the existing ones or create a new dataframe (doesn't matter that much).

This is the code I have so far that does the job (even if not the most elegant, it get's the job done):

```
path = r'"thePathToData\PL_calc\Data_NIR' 
idx = 0

#Create the DataFrame with all the data from the path above, use the filenames as column names
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.asc"))
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, usecols=[1],  sep='\t') for f in all_files), axis=1) #usecol=1 for the spectrum only

fileNames = [] # create a list for the filenames
for i in range(0,len(all_files)):
    fileNames.append(all_files[i][71:-4])

df.columns = fileNames # assign the filenames as columns
wavelengths = pd.read_csv(all_files[0], usecols=[0],  sep='\t') # add the wavelength column as first column of the dataframe
df.insert(loc=idx, column='Wavelength', value=wavelengths)
```

If I plot just the head of the DF it looks like this:

```
Wavelength  F8BT_Pure_Batch1_px1_spectra_4V  \ ...
0    478.0708                        -3.384101   
1    478.3917                        -1.580399   
2    478.7126                        -0.323580   
3    479.0334                        -1.131425   
4    479.3542                         1.202728
```

The complete DF is:

```
1599 rows × 46 columns
```

**Question 1:**

I can't quite find an automated (dynamic) way of multiplying each col with the first one, essentially this:

```
for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
    df[[i]] = df[[0]] * df[[i]]
```

**Question 2:**

Why does this work:

```
df['F8BT_Pure_Batch1_px1_spectra_4V'] = df['Wavelength']*df['F8BT_Pure_Batch1_px1_spectra_4V']
```

while this doesn't and gives me an `"IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds"`

```
df[[1]] = df[[0]]*df[[1]]
```

But when I `print(df[['Wavelength']]) Name: Wavelength, dtype: float64` and `print(df[[0]]) [1599 rows x 1 columns]` I get the same numbers..

**Question 3:**

Why does this `df[fileNames] = df[fileNames].multiply(df.Wavelength)` give me a `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`? All the columns are of the same length (1599 rows long, 0-1598 and a total of 46 columns in this case). `fileNames` contains the names of the imported files and the names of the columns of the dataframe.

**Many many thanks** in advance for your help...

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

To multiply your wavelength column by every other column in your DataFrame, you can use:

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].mul(df['Wavelength'], axis=0)
```

This assumes your wavelength column is the first column.

**Question 2**

Selecting columns like that using an integer is asking for columns of your DataFrame that are named 0, 1, etc., as ints. There are none in your DataFrame. To select columns by index number look into the documentation for [pandas' iloc method.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

**Question 3**

When you call `df[fileNames]`, you are getting a a DataFrame with the same number of columns as the length of your list `fileNames`. Your code `df[fileNames].multiply(df.Wavelength)` is not giving you a DataFrame with the same number of columns as `df[fileNames]`, hence you cannot assign the values. Using the `axis=0` parameter in the multiply function is working for me.

Comment: Fantastic... Thank you so much for your help! I will study a bit on the iloc methods...